# How to click unread email in gmail with specific subject say "First_name"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click unread email(new email) in the inbox with subject "Test"

This function currently clicks the old email with the subject "Test". I want perform this function for unread email with subject "Test"

```
public static WebElement executeVerifyEmail(WebDriver driver) 
{

    try
    {
        GmailLogin.waitforVisible(driver, GmailLogin.Logo(driver));
        List<WebElement> emaillist=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='bog']"));

        for(int i=0; i<emaillist.size(); i++){
            if(emaillist.get(i).getText().contains("TEST"))
            {
                emaillist.get(i).click();
                System.out.println("Email clicked");
                break;
            }
        }

    }catch(org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex)
    {       
    ex.getMessage();        
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: gmail has an API... you should use it.

Comment: Apparently your xpath expression `//span[@class='bog']` does not locate the emails you want to click on. So you need to adjust your xpath as appropriate. Without HTML of your web page, no one can help you. By the way: Think about your exception handling (print message to some output), return value (always returning null is rather useless) and method declaration (if you do not need a static context, don't use any)

Comment: I am doing this operation in gmail lnbox so HTML is common

Comment: Ok, then any Gmail user might help you. I don't use Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to amend your [XPath selector](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) to look into [child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/child) span like:

   ```
   List<WebElement> emaillist=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='bog']/span"));
   ```
2. You need to amend your condition to check [font-weight](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) property, for read emails it will be `400` and for unread it will be `700`

   ```
   if (emaillist.get(i).getText().contains("TEST") && emaillist.get(i).getCssValue("font-weight").equals("700")) {
   ```

Comment: I tried your code its not actually clicking recent unread email.